# Changing Colours of meta

Tags: feature-request, support, design, meta

Looking at the bar that comes up when a question has new activity in meta, I became annoyed that I couldn't read it. I have also noticed that the same colours are used in several places around the meta site. Could I suggest that these colours be changed to something that has a bit more contrast. Light grey on white is not a good combination. I have also noted that it has been brought up before ([here](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/408/meta-site-flag-menu-is-unreadable)), but that issue has still not adequately fixed.

For Example:

> [image]

and

> [image]

and

> [image]

and

> [image]

and

> [image]

Comment: My eyes! I can't unsee :(

Comment: I'll see if I can gather some attention from SE admins/site designers on this topic.

Answer (score 4):

I do have to agree, the Meta site for Photography is inverted in a rather disconcerting way. I like the darker base background, but all the white everywhere really does burn the eyes. It would be nice to maybe see those lights inverted into darks, and just have PhotoMeta be dark all around. Or at least, darker all around, without any white at all.